# How to use Auto Layout constraints to fit 2 labels with variable size in a table cell which height is estimated using estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, ios-autolayout

I have the following layout with the following constraints.

When I run it, it looks just as desired. The cell height adjusts to fit all of the text.

However, I see the following warning in the Issue Navigator and I do not understand why.

**2 views are vertically ambiguous**

- **Height and vertical position are ambiguous for View**
- **Height is ambiguous for View**

*Layout:* 
[image]

*Constraints:*

- View (cell wrapper view for all elements in the cell)

  [image]

  - View (option 1 wrapper view)

    [image]

    - Button (option 1 button)

      [image]
    - Label (option 1 label)

      [image]
  - View (option 2 wrapper view)

    [image]

    - Button (option 2 button)

      [image]
    - Label (option 2 label)

      [image]

*Table View Controller code:*

```
    import UIKit

class SelectionTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Hide navigation bar
        self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    // MARK: Hide status bar
    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The storyboard seems to be complaining because it doesn't know how tall the cell's view is going to be, it doesn't know you are going to supply a height at runtime using `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath`. All your constraints are relative to the superviews or other views and as a result there are infinite ways to satisfy those.

The easiest way to just suppress those warnings is to give the content view of the cell an explicit height, and then on the right navigator check the 'remove at build time' box for that constraint (find it on the left navigator, and click on it there).

[image]

Giving an explicit number will allow the compiler to give explicit values to the height and y positions of those views which should resolve the warnings you are getting. Then removing that constraint should allow the cell to dynamically resize in the code using the methods you have implemented.

Comment: I tried adding a height constraint to both wrapper views in question and I checked the 'Remove at build time' option like you suggested, but after updating all constraints after this changes everything just got out of place and the height for the main wrapper view is now zero so I can't see any of the elements anymore. What specific constraint to and to which elements should I apply your suggestion to?

Comment: I added a height constraint to the 3 wrapper views (the main wrapper view containing everything, and the 2 sub wrapper views for each option). I have each an estimated height and then checked the 'Remove at build time' option as suggested. This seems to have done the trick, I don't see the warning anymore and it still looks fine when I run it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your buttons do not have any top and bottom constraints to their superviews' edges. Thus, their superviews (the two wrapper views) do not know their height.

Comment: I centered the buttons by adding the constraint "Align center Y to superview" because I need the buttons to be aligned with the text depending on the size of the text, that is why I have the wrapper view. I agree with you that the buttons could be a problem but to verify it I deleted the buttons altogether and ran it and I still see the same warning so the buttons are not the issue.

Comment: @Jace In that case, I think your two superviews are confusing about their heights. You set wrapper view 2's bottom to align with its superview but also  label 2's bottom edge to align with wrapper view 2. But we know that label has its own height set (depends on its content). Thus, wrapper view 2 does not know how to set its height.  To solve it, you could try removing `Bottom space to superview` constraints in wrapper view 1 and 2.

Comment: removing the bottom space to superview constraint did get rid of the warning but now when I run the view just gets cut off and I can only see about 25% of what used to be on the screen.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot for it? But I guess you can set the line number of label to 0 to give it as many lines as it requests.